# Does normalizing strings increase SELECT performance in SQLite?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, normalization

I just read [Coding Horror: Maybe Normalizing Isn't Normal](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html), where they particularly say normalization decreases performance of SELECT queries because of the many `INNER JOIN` statements.

However I have a table where I intended to put several TEXT columns in separate tables so I can compare integer indexes instead of strings, but now that I read the article, I'm not sure if I should do it.

As an example, if we compare this denormalized table:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (country TEXT, city TEXT, address TEXT);
SELECT address FROM addresses WHERE Country=? AND City=?;
```

With the normalized form:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE cities (name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE addresses (country INT, city INT, address TEXT);
SELECT addresses.address FROM addresses INNER JOIN countries ON countries.ROWID=addresses.country INNER JOIN cities ON cities.ROWID==addresses.city WHERE countries.name=? AND cities.name=?;
```

Is the second form slower, faster, or the same speed as the first form for SQLite in particular?

Comment: They are wrong. Normalization is a good thing.

Comment: So it will increase the speed of my SELECT query? It looks exactly like the example, only the column names are different :)

Comment: The article also says that it doesn't matter, not until you hit the millions or billions (in number of users/posts, etc.)

Comment: Unless you have a one to many relationship between people and addresses, the fact that you have an address table at all is odd.

Comment: That was a made up example, not my actual table. I just have 2 text columns which I could put in a different table. The columns hold values that are frequently the same, just like countries and cities would frequently be the same text.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people don't know what *normalization* means.

If you require every row in every table to have an ID number, and you use those ID numbers as foreign keys, you'll need to do a *lot* of joins to get useful information. (ID numbers aren't useful information in this sense.)

But normalization has to do with identifying dependencies and projecting new relations. Normalization *doesn't* have anything to do with ID numbers.

In your table, you replaced text with ID numbers. That's not normalization; that's just replacing text with ID numbers.

In most cases, the text will perform better than the ID numbers and joins. I've tested this myself, and written about it several times on both stackoverflow.com and on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your answer leaves me a bit confused. Isn't splitting data into separate tables to avoid duplication what normalization is about? In my example, I could have 10000 rows where 'United States' is being repeated.

Comment: In the sense you're using the term *duplication*, no, that's not what normalization is about. Replacing "United States" in 10000 rows with the value 123 isn't normalization. That kind of replacement doesn't change the normal form; if the table were in 3NF before the replacement, it will still be in 3NF after the replacement. And you'll still have duplication. You'll just be duplicating numbers instead of strings.

Comment: But coming from a C++ background, numbers are smaller than strings, and also comparing numbers is faster than comparing strings. But may be SQLite uses some very optimized comparison operation. Besides, what if the third column held PNG images as binary blobs, each 50 KB in size, and they repeat a lot, the same PNG can appear multiple times? Would my 'replacing' PNGs with IDs be normalization then?

Comment: Normalization never asks, "How wide is the column?" or "How fast can I compare values?"  Replacing PNGs with ID numbers is not normalization, although it might be a good design decision for other reasons.  (Many database design decisions have nothing to do with normalization.) Needing no joins is often faster than needing two joins, regardless of the data type. You don't have to take my word for it; do some tests yourself. (Don't forget to add necessary indexes.)

Comment: OK, thanks, I talked with a colleague and I really had a wrong idea about what normalization is. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Data normalization has to do with conformance to a succession of ever more restrictive normal forms.  Table decomposition is the usual transformation to achieve a higher normal form.  Normalization is only secondarily about performance.  It's mostly about avoiding databases that contradict themselves.